# Meteor Tutorial: Creating an App - Step 6 | Error executing Cordova command for device and emulator (Linux Mint Rosa)

Tags: java, android, linux, cordova, meteor

I am doing the [Meteor creating an app tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile). For step 6 I tried to run the application on the emulator and on my HTC one mini 2 device. It doesn't work.

**For the emulator:**

- I successfully installed the latest JDK
- When I execute `java -version` I get

  `java version "1.8.0_77"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)`
- When I execute `javac -version` I get `javac 1.8.0_77`
- I successfully installed Android Studios
- And all requirements that are checked by Meteor (JDK, Android SDK, etc.) are toggled with a checkmark.

When I enter `meteor run android` I get this error message

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed: /home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
   { [CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found.
   1. Download desired System Image by running: /home/lencewa/Android/Sdk/tools/android sdk
   2. Create an AVD by running: /home/lencewa/Android/Sdk/tools/android avd
   HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
   ]
   name: 'CordovaError',
   message: 'No emulator images (avds) found.\n1. Download desired System Image by running: /home/lencewa/Android/Sdk/tools/android sdk\n2. Create an AVD by running:
   /home/lencewa/Android/Sdk/tools/android avd\nHINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver\n',
   code: 0,
   context: undefined } 'No emulator images (avds) found.\n1. Download desired System Image by running: /home/lencewa/Android/Sdk/tools/android sdk\n2. Create an AVD by running:
   /home/lencewa/Android/Sdk/tools/android avd\nHINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver\n\n    at
   /home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:170:29\n    at _fulfilled
   (/home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)\n    at self.promiseDispatch.done
   (/home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)\n    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)\n    at
   /home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44\n    at runSingle
   (/home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)\n    at flush
   (/home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

/home/lencewa/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.1.nl5mvb++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

And I don't know what the problem might be.

**For the device:**

- I enabled the hidden developer option
- I enabled the USB-Debugging
- And when I enter `adb devices` I get

  `List of devices attached 
  SH46RWR05243    device`
- But I get this error message when I run `meteor run android-device`:

  ```
  WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the same network, and that the network configuration
       allows clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
  => Errors executing Cordova commands:         

     While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
     Error: Command failed: /home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --device
     Error code 1 for command: /home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew with args:
     cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/lencewa/MeteorToDoList/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
     undefined
     at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

  /home/lencewa/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.1.nl5mvb++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
    throw error;
          ^
  ExitWithCode:1
  ```

I really don't see the problem and I didn't find an appropriate solution in the Internet to fix this. And I strictly followed the Tutorial steps.